# Calculating a Measure of the Geometric Complexity of Planar Closed Polylines

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

Let $\lbrace p_1,\ \dots,\ p_n\rbrace$ be a set of points  in the Euclidean plane and let $T_0 :=\left(p_1,\ \dots,\ p_n,p_1\right)$ be a Hamilton cycle through the set of points.

> **Question:**
>
> What is the complexity of determining the number $k$ of iterations that are required to arrive at tour $T_k$, which doesn't contain reflex corners and is generated via $$T_{i+1} := T_i\ \setminus \lbrace p\ |\ \left(p-pred_{T_i}(p)\right) \times \left(succ_{T_i}(p)-p\right) \ge 0\rbrace$$ 
>   $$k := \min_i{\lbrace p\ |\ \left(p-pred_{T_i}(p)\right) \times \left(succ_{T_i}(p)-p\right) \lt 0\rbrace}=\emptyset$$

Remarks:

- $T_k$ may be a degenerated tour, that consists of only a single point; that is for example the case, if the points are placed on a [Cardioid]  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid) and the cusp is one of the points.
- $k$ might also serve as a measure of the geometric complexity of tours and especially of simple polygons; therefore I would not be surprised if the above described iteration has already been mentioned somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Store $T_i$ in a double-linked list, and maintain a list $D$ of elements of $T_i$ that need to be deleted because of angle condition. On each step delete every element of (current version of) $D$ from $T_i$ to obtain $T_{i + 1}$. When removing $x$ from $T_i$, we can see that only neighbours of $x$ may change status, hence the extra cost of maintaining $D$ is constant per removal. Obviously, the total number of removals is $O(n)$. The total complexity is $O(n)$.

Comment: I can't qui te follow your argumentation because some of the reflex vertices can also be in convex configuration and that in a fractal manner, so I think that it is unlikely, that a simple $O(n)$ algorithm exists. By the way, the algorithmic complexity is measured in the number of arithmetic operations that have to be performed until the algorithm terminates with an answer. Maybe you recheck your answer.

Comment: The list $D$ contains all reflex vertices of $T_i$, and gets updated as we delete reflex vertices from $T_i$ using $D$ (or rather a copy of $D$ to avoid read-modify conflicts). The number of operations needed to go from $T_i$ to $T_{i + 1}$ is linear in $|T_i \backslash T_{i + 1}|$, hence the total number of operations is $O(n)$. Are there particular details you would like me to elaborate on?

Comment: A test of your algorithm on a Koch snowflake https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake would convince me